# Get Log off event from system

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, logout

I am doing an application which is used to clear the Temp files, history etc, when the user log off. So how can I know if the system is going to logoff (in C#)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a property in **Environment** class that tells about if shutdown process has started:

```
Environment.HasShutDownStarted
```

But after some googling I found out that this may be of help to you:

```
 using Microsoft.Win32;

 //during init of your application bind to this event  
 SystemEvents.SessionEnding += 
            new SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);

 void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (Environment.HasShutdownStarted)
     {
         //Tackle Shutdown
     }
     else
     {
         //Tackle log off
     }
  }
```

But if you only want to clear temp file then I think distinguishing between shutdown or log off is not of any consequence to you.

Comment: Keep in mind though, on Vista+ you have very little time to do stuff during shutdown, so make sure that you can't block or wait for any reason (i.e. trying to delete a file that might be on a network share, etc...)

Comment: thanks @Paul then should it be advisable to make an entry somewhere so that windows clear the stuff on next reboot or login?

Comment: what is SystemEvents ?

Comment: Shutdown, log off...shutdown using Wake On LAN ?

Answer (score 9):

If you specifically need the log-off event, you can modify the code provided in TheVillageIdiot's answer as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

//during init of your application bind to this event   
SystemEvents.SessionEnding += 
    new SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);

void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e) 
{     
    if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.Logoff) 
    {  
        // insert your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI and watch the Win32_ComputerShutdownEvent where Type is equal to 0. You can find more information about this event [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394101(VS.85).aspx), and more about using WMI in .NET [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720264.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **Windows Form**, you can handle the `FormClosing` event, then check the `e.CloseReason` enum value to determine if it equals to `CloseReason.WindowsShutDown`.

```cs
private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't "User log off" and "System shutdown" different things?

Comment: @UweKeim the CloseReason enum do not consider "User log off" scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason?view=windowsdesktop-7.0