# .NET WinForms - How to listen to events for system LogOff, User Locked, Hibernate Started and System resumed?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, events

I want to listen to events in my windows forms .NET application for the following system wide events :

Log Off
Lock Windows
Hibernate Started
Sleep Started
System Resumed

Are these possible?

Thanks

Comment: Most of this is covered by the SystemEvents class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look WMI (Windows media instrumentation). You would need to create event watchers for the above mentioned events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340%28VS.80%29.aspx

Useful links:

[Get Log off event from system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984881/get-log-off-event-from-system)

How to create a WMI Event Watcher for a user logoff event?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0c1bded8-0cce-4260-bd28-4b4ffce0d27d

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/WMI-Programming-with-Visual-BasicNET-Trapping-System-Events/1/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, you can use the WMI to trap events.
I'm adding some code sample I wrote few years back (hope it will still work since it was written on VS2010 With .Net3.5)

Here's a class that gathers all the events

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class PowerMessageFilter
    Implements IMessageFilter
    Const WM_POWERBROADCAST As Integer = &H218
    Const PBT_APMSUSPEND As Integer = &H4
    Const PBT_APMSTANDBY As Integer = &H5
    Const PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND As Integer = &H7
    Const PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY As Integer = &H8

   Protected Sub reportpowerchange(ByVal reason As Integer)
       Dim report As String = String.Empty
       Select Case (reason)
           Case PBT_APMSUSPEND
               report = "system is suspending operation "
               suspend_service()
               Exit Select
           Case PBT_APMSTANDBY
               report = "system is standing by "
               suspend_service()
               Exit Select
           Case PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND
               report = "operation resuming after suspension."
               suspend_service()
               Exit Select
           Case PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY
               report = "operation resuming after stand by."
               suspend_service()
           Exit Select
       End Select
   End Sub

   Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
       If WM_POWERBROADCAST = m.Msg Then
           Console.Out.WriteLine("Power Broadcast recieved.")
           Dim reason As Integer = m.WParam.ToInt32()
           reportpowerchange(reason)
       End If
       Return False
   End Function

   Private Sub suspend_service()
      ' Your suspend code
   End Sub
End Class
```

Now, for the listener, I had a Win32 service that ran in the background and did the listening work

```
Dim Filter As New PowerMessageFilter 'The Standby/Hibernation Filter catch;
Application.AddMessageFilter(Filter)
```

I sorry that I don't have any references for the sites I've taken the examples from, I guess it was probably from the MSDN links above.

Hope it can help,
Liron